# How do I fix the following code so I get a reversed linked list for the output?

Tags: java, data-structures, linked-list, nodes, reverse

The following code is my attempt at implementing `SinglyLinkedListNode` and `SinglyLinkedList` classes and use the `SinglyLinkedListNode reverse(SinglyLinkedListNode head)` method to reverse this linked list.

The input consists of the first line detailing the number of test cases, `t`. And for each test case, the first line, `n`, represents the number of elements in the linked list. The next `n` number of lines will each contain an element from this list such that the input is as follows:

```
1 (number of test cases)
5 (number of elements in list)
1 (element in list)
2 (element in list)
3 (element in list)
4 (element in list)
5 (element in list)
```

How can I fix the following code so that it can print this reversed linked list, such that the output would be as follows:

`5 4 3 2 1`

As my code instead prints out the following:

```
1
5
1
2
3
4
5

1 2 3 4 5
```

My code:

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class ReverseLinkedList {

    static class SinglyLinkedListNode {
        public int data;
        public SinglyLinkedListNode next;

        public SinglyLinkedListNode(int nodeData) {
            data = nodeData;
            next = null;
        }
    }

    static class SinglyLinkedList {
        private SinglyLinkedListNode head;
        private SinglyLinkedListNode tail;

        public SinglyLinkedList() {
            SinglyLinkedListNode head = null;
            SinglyLinkedListNode tail = null;
        }

        public void insertNode(int nodeData) {
            SinglyLinkedListNode node = new SinglyLinkedListNode(nodeData);

            if (this.head == null) {
                this.head = node;
            } else {
                this.tail.next = node;
            }

            this.tail = node;
        }

        public SinglyLinkedListNode reverse(SinglyLinkedListNode head) {
            SinglyLinkedListNode previous = null;
            SinglyLinkedListNode current = head;
            SinglyLinkedListNode next = null;
            while (current != null) {
                next = current.next;
                current.next = previous;
                previous = current;
                current = next;
            }
            return previous;
        }

        public void printLinkedList() {
            SinglyLinkedListNode node = head;
            while (node != null) {
                System.out.print(node.data + " ");
                node = node.next;
            }
        }
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
        SinglyLinkedList list = new SinglyLinkedList();

        int testCases = input.nextInt();

        if (testCases <= 10) {
            input.nextLine();
            int size = input.nextInt();
            if (size <= 1000) {
                for (int i = 0; i < size; i++) {
                    list.insertNode(input.nextInt());
                }
                list.reverse(list.tail);
                list.printLinkedList();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: you also need to assign head = prev before returning and also return head

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
use list.reverse(list.head)
```

and modify your reverse method as

```
 SinglyLinkedListNode previous = null; 
    SinglyLinkedListNode current = head; 
    SinglyLinkedListNode next = null; 
    while (current != null) { 
        next = current.next; 
        current.next = previous; 
        previous = current; 
        current = next; 
    } 
    head= previous; 
    return head;
```

Also in your method printLinkedList set

```
      SinglyLinkedListNode node = tail; // instead of head
```

Comment: I made those changes, but I get an output of just '1'.

Comment: @Broadsword You also need to set tail instead of head in printLinkedList method, similar to as I have done in my answer

Answer (score 0):

You should pass head of the linkedlist instead of tail to reverse method.

```
list.reverse(list.head);
```

Comment: Hi, thanks for your suggestion. I made that change but still got the same output as you see in the original post.